# Entity Framework conditional ThenInclude based on preceding Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In EF7, how can I conditionally ThenInclude an item, based on the value of a prior Include?

I have a Case object which contains many Logs.  Each Log contains a LogText.

```
class Case
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; }
}

class Log
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public Case Case { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public LogText LogText { get; set; }
}

class LogText
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I want to load a particular Case, and all of its Logs, but I only want to load the LogText for particular Logs based on their Type.

I can load all the Logs/LogText via:

```
var cse = context.Cases.Include(c => c.Logs).ThenInclude(l => l.LogText);
```

I can load only the Logs matching my Type filter via:

```
var cse = context.Cases.Include(c => c.Logs.Where(l => l.Type==1)).ThenInclude(l => l.LogText);
```

But, I can't work out how to include *all* Logs, *but only* LogText for Logs which have Type==1

Any suggestions?

Comment: The [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) examples show you can Include the same relation multiple times with different conditions and configuration. Perhaps `.Include(c=>c.Logs).Include(c => c.Logs.Where(l => l.Type==1)).ThenInclude(l => l.LogText)` will work?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The link also says *"**Each** included navigation allows **only one** unique set of filter operations. In cases where multiple Include operations are applied for a given collection navigation (blog.Posts in the examples below), filter operations **can only** be specified on one of them"*. Which means the answer to OP is "not possible".

Comment: Yeah, doing two separate Includes only gives the .Where() version.

Comment: I think you have to write two queries, but you can send / receive everything in one go by using `.Concat()` or `.Union()` (not sure cause I'm currently AFK)

Comment: @Oliver be interested to see what you come up with, so far I'm getting errors about different Include clauses when trying to Concat two different queries.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the only option I have is to load the filtered Include/ThenInclude and after the fact, explicity load the full Logs collection.  This means two database hits instead of one, which is not ideal.

```
var cse = context.Cases.Include(c => c.Logs.Where(l => l.Type==1)).ThenInclude(l => l.LogText).FirstOrDefault();
context.Entry(cse).Collection(c => c.Logs).Query().Load();
```